# Sidebar and footer not being called properly

Tags: php, html, css

I am designiong software in CI framework and have seoarated sidebar and footer in separate files and trying to include them. However the sidebar is coming on the top and footer bar is not getting applied properly. not sure where I am going wrong. Below is the code :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>search</title>
        <?php include_once 'header.php'; ?>
    </head>
        <body class="fixed-nav sticky-footer bg-dark">
          <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <?php include_once 'sidebar.php'; ?>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <!-- Breadcrumbs-->
              <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                  <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active">View/Add Clients</li>
              </ol>
              <!--Button to add Client-->
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-plus" style="color:white"></i> Add Client</button>
              <br>
              <br>
              <!-- Example DataTables Card-->
              <div class="card mb-3">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <i class="fa fa-table"></i> View Client Details</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Name</th>
                          <th>Station</th>
                          <th>Payment Due</th>
                          <th>Dispatch Date</th>
                          <th>Bill Date</th>
                          <th>Payment Date</th>
                          <th>Invoice</th>
                          <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Name</th>
                          <th>Station</th>
                          <th>Payment Due</th>
                          <th>Dispatch Date</th>
                          <th>Bill Date</th>
                          <th>Payment Date</th>
                          <th>Invoice</th>
                          <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                      </tfoot>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Name</td>
                          <td>Station</td>
                          <td>Payment Due</td>
                          <td>Dispatch Date</td>
                          <td>Bill Date</td>
                          <td>Payment Date</td>
                          <td>Invoice</td>
                          <td>Action</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid-->
            <!-- /.content-wrapper-->
           </div>                    

              </div>
            </div>


         <!--<div>-->


           <!-- Modal to add Client-->
         <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

              <!-- Modal content-->
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Add Client Details</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <input type="submit" name="clientsubmit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
           <!-- Modal Finishes-->   
        <?php  include_once 'footer.php'; ?> 
</body>     
</html>
```

While pressing F12 the code seems to behave properly so not sure if I am missing somethiong here

sidebar code

```
 <!-- Navigation-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="search.php">Polyrope Icon</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-sidenav" id="exampleAccordion">
        <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="administration">
          <a class="nav-link nav-link-collapse collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#sysadmin" data-parent="#exampleAccordion">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-wrench"></i>
            <span class="nav-link-text">System Administration</span>
          </a>
          <ul class="sidenav-second-level collapse" id="sysadmin">
            <li>
              <a href="navbar.php">Navbar</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="manpass.php">Password Management</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="client">
          <a class="nav-link" href="search.php">
            <i class="fa fa-group"></i>
            <span class="nav-link-text">Client Management</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Invoice">
          <a class="nav-link nav-link-collapse collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#invoice" data-parent="#exampleAccordion">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-file"></i>
            <span class="nav-link-text">Invoice Management</span>
          </a>
          <ul class="sidenav-second-level collapse" id="invoice">
            <li>
              <a href="createinvoice.php">Raise Invoice</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="traninvoice.php">Transfer Invoice</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="transport">
          <a class="nav-link" href="transport.php">
            <i class="fa fa-truck"></i>
            <span class="nav-link-text">Transport Management</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav sidenav-toggler">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-center" id="sidenavToggler">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-left"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

footer.php

```
<footer class="sticky-footer">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="text-center">
          <small>Copyright © Your Website 2018</small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- Scroll to Top Button-->
    <a class="scroll-to-top rounded" href="#page-top">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
    </a>
    <!-- Logout Modal-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ready to Leave?</h5>
            <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">Select "Logout" below if you are ready to end your current session.</div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="login.html">Logout</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js');?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js');?>"></script>
    <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js');?>"></script>
    <!-- Page level plugin JavaScript-->
    <!--<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js');?>"></script>-->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js');?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.js');?>"></script>
    <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/sb-admin.min.js');?>"></script>
    <!-- Custom scripts for this page-->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/sb-admin-datatables.min.js');?>"></script>
    <!--<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/sb-admin-charts.min.js');?>"></script>-->
```

CSS

```
html{position:relative;min-height:100%}body{overflow-x:hidden}body.sticky-footer{margin-bottom:56px}body.sticky-footer .content-wrapper{min-height:calc(100vh - 56px - 56px)}body.fixed-nav{padding-top:56px}.content-wrapper{min-height:calc(100vh - 56px);padding-top:1rem}.scroll-to-top{position:fixed;right:15px;bottom:3px;display:none;width:50px;height:50px;text-align:center;color:#fff;background:rgba(52,58,64,.5);line-height:45px}.scroll-to-top:focus,.scroll-to-top:hover{color:#fff}.scroll-to-top:hover{background:#343a40}.scroll-to-top i{font-weight:800}.smaller{font-size:.7rem}.o-hidden{overflow:hidden!important}.z-0{z-index:0}.z-1{z-index:1}#mainNav .navbar-collapse{overflow:auto;max-height:75vh}#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link{cursor:pointer}#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .nav-link-collapse:after{float:right;content:'\f107';font-family:FontAwesome}#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .nav-link-collapse.collapsed:after{content:'\f105'}#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .sidenav-second-level,#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .sidenav-third-level{padding-left:0}#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .sidenav-second-level>li>a,#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .sidenav-third-level>li>a{display:block;padding:.5em 0}#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .sidenav-second-level>li>a:focus,#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .sidenav-second-level>li>a:hover,#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .sidenav-third-level>li>a:focus,#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .sidenav-third-level>li>a:hover{text-decoration:none}#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .sidenav-second-level>li>a{padding-left:1em}#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .sidenav-third-level>li>a{padding-left:2em}#mainNav .navbar-collapse .sidenav-toggler{display:none}#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav>.nav-item.dropdown>.nav-link{position:relative;min-width:45px}#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav>.nav-item.dropdown>.nav-link:after{float:right;width:auto;content:'\f105';border:none;font-family:FontAwesome}#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav>.nav-item.dropdown>.nav-link .indicator{position:absolute;top:5px;left:21px;font-size:10px}#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav>.nav-item.dropdown.show>.nav-link:after{content:'\f107'}#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav>.nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu>.dropdown-item>.dropdown-message{overflow:hidden;max-width:none;text-overflow:ellipsis}@media (min-width:992px){#mainNav .navbar-brand{width:250px}#mainNav .navbar-collapse{overflow:visible;max-height:none}#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;-webkit-flex-direction:column;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column;margin-top:56px}#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item{width:250px;padding:0}#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item>.nav-link{padding:1em}#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item .sidenav-second-level,#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item .sidenav-third-level{padding-left:0;list-style:none}#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item .sidenav-second-level>li,#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item .sidenav-third-level>li{width:250px}#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item .sidenav-second-level>li>a,#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item .sidenav-third-level>li>a{padding:1em}#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item .sidenav-second-level>li>a{padding-left:2.75em}#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item .sidenav-third-level>li>a{padding-left:3.75em}#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav>.nav-item.dropdown>.nav-link{min-width:0}#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav>.nav-item.dropdown>.nav-link:after{width:24px;text-align:center}#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav>.nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu>.dropdown-item>.dropdown-message{max-width:300px}}#mainNav.fixed-top .sidenav-toggler{display:none}@media (min-width:992px){#mainNav.fixed-top .navbar-sidenav{height:calc(100vh - 112px)}#mainNav.fixed-top .sidenav-toggler{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;display:flex;-webkit-flex-direction:column;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column;margin-top:calc(100vh - 56px)}#mainNav.fixed-top .sidenav-toggler>.nav-item{width:250px;padding:0}#mainNav.fixed-top .sidenav-toggler>.nav-item>.nav-link{padding:1em}}#mainNav.fixed-top.navbar-dark .sidenav-toggler{background-color:#212529}#mainNav.fixed-top.navbar-dark .sidenav-toggler a i{color:#adb5bd}#mainNav.fixed-top.navbar-light .sidenav-toggler{background-color:#dee2e6}#mainNav.fixed-top.navbar-light .sidenav-toggler a i{color:rgba(0,0,0,.5)}body.sidenav-toggled #mainNav.fixed-top .sidenav-toggler{overflow-x:hidden;width:55px}body.sidenav-toggled #mainNav.fixed-top .sidenav-toggler .nav-item,body.sidenav-toggled #mainNav.fixed-top .sidenav-toggler .nav-link{width:55px!important}body.sidenav-toggled #mainNav.fixed-top #sidenavToggler i{-webkit-transform:scaleX(-1);-moz-transform:scaleX(-1);-o-transform:scaleX(-1);transform:scaleX(-1);filter:FlipH;-ms-filter:FlipH}#mainNav.static-top .sidenav-toggler{display:none}@media (min-width:992px){#mainNav.static-top .sidenav-toggler{display:flex}}body.sidenav-toggled #mainNav.static-top #sidenavToggler i{-webkit-transform:scaleX(-1);-moz-transform:scaleX(-1);-o-transform:scaleX(-1);transform:scaleX(-1);filter:FlipH;-ms-filter:FlipH}.content-wrapper{overflow-x:hidden;background:#fff}@media (min-width:992px){.content-wrapper{margin-left:250px}}#sidenavToggler i{font-weight:800}.navbar-sidenav-tooltip.show{display:none}@media (min-width:992px){body.sidenav-toggled .content-wrapper{margin-left:55px}}body.sidenav-toggled .navbar-sidenav{width:55px}body.sidenav-toggled .navbar-sidenav .nav-link-text{display:none}body.sidenav-toggled .navbar-sidenav .nav-item,body.sidenav-toggled .navbar-sidenav .nav-link{width:55px!important}body.sidenav-toggled .navbar-sidenav .nav-item:after,body.sidenav-toggled .navbar-sidenav .nav-link:after{display:none}body.sidenav-toggled .navbar-sidenav .nav-item{white-space:nowrap}body.sidenav-toggled .navbar-sidenav-tooltip.show{display:flex}#mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .nav-link-collapse:after{color:#868e96}#mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item>.nav-link{color:#868e96}#mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item>.nav-link:hover{color:#adb5bd}#mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item .sidenav-second-level>li>a,#mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item .sidenav-third-level>li>a{color:#868e96}#mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item .sidenav-second-level>li>a:focus,#mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item .sidenav-second-level>li>a:hover,#mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item .sidenav-third-level>li>a:focus,#mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item .sidenav-third-level>li>a:hover{color:#adb5bd}#mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav>.nav-item.dropdown>.nav-link:after{color:#adb5bd}@media (min-width:992px){#mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav{background:#343a40}#mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav li.active a{color:#fff!important;background-color:#495057}#mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav li.active a:focus,#mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav li.active a:hover{color:#fff}#mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item .sidenav-second-level,#mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item .sidenav-third-level{background:#343a40}}#mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .nav-link-collapse:after{color:rgba(0,0,0,.5)}#mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item>.nav-link{color:rgba(0,0,0,.5)}#mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item>.nav-link:hover{color:rgba(0,0,0,.7)}#mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item .sidenav-second-level>li>a,#mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item .sidenav-third-level>li>a{color:rgba(0,0,0,.5)}#mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item .sidenav-second-level>li>a:focus,#mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item .sidenav-second-level>li>a:hover,#mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item .sidenav-third-level>li>a:focus,#mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item .sidenav-third-level>li>a:hover{color:rgba(0,0,0,.7)}#mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav>.nav-item.dropdown>.nav-link:after{color:rgba(0,0,0,.5)}@media (min-width:992px){#mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav{background:#f8f9fa}#mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav li.active a{color:#000!important;background-color:#e9ecef}#mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav li.active a:focus,#mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav li.active a:hover{color:#000}#mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item .sidenav-second-level,#mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav>.nav-item .sidenav-third-level{background:#f8f9fa}}.card-body-icon{position:absolute;z-index:0;top:-25px;right:-25px;font-size:5rem;-webkit-transform:rotate(15deg);-ms-transform:rotate(15deg);transform:rotate(15deg)}@media (min-width:576px){.card-columns{column-count:1}}@media (min-width:768px){.card-columns{column-count:2}}@media (min-width:1200px){.card-columns{column-count:2}}.card-login{max-width:25rem}.card-register{max-width:40rem}footer.sticky-footer{position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0;width:100%;height:56px;background-color:#e9ecef;line-height:55px}@media (min-width:992px){footer.sticky-footer{width:calc(100% - 250px)}}@media (min-width:992px){body.sidenav-toggled footer.sticky-footer{width:calc(100% - 55px)}}
```

Comment: Can you include the CSS, sidebar.php, and the footer.php code?

Comment: @Jonny edited the question to include code